# Installing Hibernate plugins in Eclipse Luna error

Tags: java, hibernate, eclipse-plugin

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.aspectj.runtime,1.8.5.20141117171500
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.ws.commons.schema,1.4.2.v201003051240
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.aspectj.ajde,1.8.5.20141117171500
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.aspectj.weaver,1.8.5.20141117171500
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ajdt.core,2.2.4.e44x-20141118-0700
```

at 13% of installing this error occurred.and installation interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse go to the menu :

```
Help > Install New Software... >
```

And then use the following url :

```
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/
```

[image]

Comment: but the problem is i'm using mint 16  in which my eclipse got crashed every time i open the marketplace .